# Implementing permissions on Liferay 7.1

Tags: liferay, osgi, liferay-dxp, liferay-7.1

I'm trying to implement permissions (resources & models ones) on Liferay 7.1. I've noted that `BaseModelPermissionChecker` is now deprecated (so I should not make my permission classes extending it). So I tried to do as indicated in [Liferay official tutorial](https://dev.liferay.com/fr/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-1/assigning-permissions-to-resources)
However, when deploying my osgi services, OSGI container indicates the following error (for model and resource permission):

```
ERROR [Refresh Thread: Equinox Container: 80bbc977-c7cb-0018-1000-82f21869d6ec][com_liferay_training_space_gradebook_service:97] [com.a.b.c.service.permission.MyEntityPermission(3887)] Field _portletResourcePermission in component class com.a.b.c.service.permission.MyEntityPermission must not be static.
```

Have you got that error ? Did I skip something ?

**EDIT**

Component created:

```
@Component(immediate = true, service = {})
public class BookResourcePermission {

public static final String ADD_BOOK = "ADD_BOOK";

@Reference(target = "(resource.name=com.x.y.mybook.model)", unbind = "-")
protected static void setPortletResourcePermission(PortletResourcePermission portletResourcePermission) {
    _portletResourcePermission = portletResourcePermission;
}

public static boolean contains(PermissionChecker permissionChecker, long groupId, String actionId) {
    return _portletResourcePermission.contains(permissionChecker, groupId, actionId);
}

private static PortletResourcePermission _portletResourcePermission;
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: it says your Field _portletResourcePermission is static ... and equinox doesn't likes that .. have you an @REFERENCE above an static field ?

Comment: yes I have an @Reference over there.

Comment: the  mentioned tutorial uses Method injection instead of property injection,. this hides the static field for equinox

Comment: Yeah at the beginning I did it like that. However, I got an exception on the build: In component <name not yet determined>, method <init>,  cannot recognize the signature of the descriptor: ()V, No interface specified on <init>]. It is the same as this one https://community.liferay.com/fr/forums/-/message_boards/message/84345299/exclusive?_com_liferay_message_boards_web_portlet_MBPortlet_showBreadcrumb=false

Comment: may be you should provide the component you have created ...

Comment: I've edited my post with the component created that throws the error.. That error is thrown at build time by AnnotationReader of bndlib.

Comment: Well, that's my mistake...It is a typo..It is due to the static modifier on the setter :-( 
It works fine now.

Comment: every osgi Service needs an Interfaces... the annotation has to be validly used... you can set Object as Class, and the service compotent registry (the SCR bundle of your runtime) needs to be used via method/ propery injection ,,, but both from object instances und not these static ones ... welcome in the osgi world, where everything is a component